# Ninject tutorials/documentations?

Tags: ninject

According to the [official site](http://ninject.org/learn): *The best place to learn about Ninject is from the [official wiki](http://wiki.github.com/ninject/ninject) on Github.*

Is that true? As a beginner, I found the [official wiki](http://wiki.github.com/ninject/ninject) not very helpful. Are there any better tutorials available? I tried Google, but didn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what context you're using it - e.g. for ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC there are a good few blog posts around (though the Web Forms are typically based on v1)

I personally found that I just wanted a thorough end-to-end understanding of what this baby can do... For that, there's no substitute for just downloading the source and reading [the tests](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/tree/master/src/Ninject.Test) - they're compact and complete and are bound to teach you a thing or two about writing good tests along the way.

(The maintainers are aware of the pain of the fact that a subset of the documentation is v1 specific, but unfortunately nobody (including myself, *blush*) has yet stepped up to the plate to do the update)

Comment: @caveman: BTW some updates have happened to the github wiki recently and watch this space (this Q prodded a little!)

Answer (score 1):

I have put up a mini tutorial on my blog:

http://stefanoricciardi.com/2011/01/21/ninject-mini-tutorial-part-1/

Hope you find that useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good tutorial for beginners at:

https://medium.com/the-liberators/a-step-by-step-guide-to-using-ninject-for-dependency-injection-in-c-68a125bd7fa4

This provides an up-front introduction to dependency injection followed by a simple but good example.